# Error with Searchview in customized Actionbar

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-styles, searchview

I customized my actionbar with this [Tool](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=dark&actionbarstyle=transparent&texture=0&hairline=1&neutralPressed=0&backColor=2D2D2D%2C100&secondaryColor=151515%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=303030%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=002E3E%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100).

Everything works well, except my Searchview in my Actionbar.

Everytime i start my Application, it crashes, caused by a nullpointer exception. 
I didn't have this error before i modified my actionbar.

Does Anyone have an idea how i could fix this problem?

Thanks for all answers

-----------------------------Error code:-----------------------

```
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): Process: com.skatepedia.android, PID: 25189
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at com.skatepedia.android.LexikonActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(LexikonActivity.java:163)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:489)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:853)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:273)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
07-29 12:57:44.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25189): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---------------------Error in Lexikon Activity:------------------

```
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_Action);

 SearchView sw = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);  // Null Pointer
```

-----------------------Styles.xml:-------------------------------

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>

  <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Example.Widget</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_example</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_example</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please chenage your code as below.

In menu.xml change the namespace of actionViewClass from android:actionViewClass to app:actionViewClass

like below

```
<item android:id="@+id/search_action"
app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
android:title="@string/action_bar_search"
**android:actionViewClass**="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
/>
```

to

```
<item android:id="@+id/search_action"
app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
android:title="@string/action_bar_search"
**app:actionViewClass**="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
/>
```

Comment: Still getting the same Error. (Sorry, i'm not able to format the code >.<
main.xml:


`   
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
       <item android:id="@+id/search_action"
  app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
  android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
  android:title="@string/search_Action"
 app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

    </menu>`

Comment: Please change your app theme 

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

Reason beeing asking for this change is that



Each activity that uses the ActionBarCompat should extend ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity directly
Each activity that uses the ActionBarCompat should declare its theme as inheriting from the ActionBarCompat themes.
Both of those I found watching the explanation video from Google. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thanks! You just saved my Day!!
I had to replace: <style name="Theme.Example" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
with: <style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
Thanks for the fast answers!

Comment: If my answer solved your issue than please vote for it.